# Opencart Google Base Feed Issue with latin letter

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am using opencart version : 2.0.1.1. having one product name : AKU SABLJASTA ŽAGA Stanley

google base feed url is:

```
mysite.com/index.php?route=feed/google_base
```

the issue is when I check the browser it displays like:
AKU SABLJASTA Ĺ˝AGA Stanley

you can see that `Ž is replaced with Ĺ˝.`

I know there must be some charset changes required. the line is coming from:

```
catalog/controller/feed/google_base.php
Line 23: $output .= '<title>' . $product['name'] . '</title>';
```

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$output .= '<title>' . iconv(mb_detect_encoding($product['name'], mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $product['name']) . '</title>';`

It detects the encoding and then convert it to **UTF-8**.

You must have **iconv** & **mbstring** extensions **enabled** in your php installation.